# Unable to send emails to my own domain through SendGrid SMTP server

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer, sendgrid

I am trying to use `SendGrid SMTP` servers to send emails from a contact form in my webpage.

I've installed `PHPMailer` into my web server and configured the `SMTP` credentials in my php form, and it's working perfectly whenever the receiver `("to")` is a `gmail` account. **However** if I change that account to one of my own domain i.e. `hello@myowndomain.net`, I never receive that email.

I don't know if I should configure anything else in my `SendGrid` account or in my `php` code.

**Here is my php code:**

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Enable SMTP debugging.
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();
//Set SMTP host name
$mail->Host = " smtp.sendgrid.net";
//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Provide username and password
$mail->Username = "apikey";
$mail->Password = "mySMTPPassword";
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
//$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
//Set TCP port to connect to
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = "test@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Full Name";

$mail->smtpConnect(
    array(
        "ssl" => array(
            "verify_peer" => false,
            "verify_peer_name" => false,
            "allow_self_signed" => true
        )
    )
);

$mail->addAddress("hello@myowndomain.net", "Recepient Name");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Contact form";
$mail->Body = "<i>You have received a new message!</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text";

if(!$mail->send())
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

EDIT:

```
I changed SMTPDebug mode to 2, and it seems everything is OK for me:

2018-08-09 14:08:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN

2018-08-09 14:08:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 

2018-08-09 14:08:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: YXBpa2V5

2018-08-09 14:08:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 

2018-08-09 14:08:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: 

2018-08-09 14:08:16 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication successful

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<test@gmail.com>

2018-08-09 14:08:16 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Sender address accepted

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<hellomyowndomain.com>

2018-08-09 14:08:16 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Recipient address accepted

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA

2018-08-09 14:08:16 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Continue

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Thu, 9 Aug 2018 07:08:16 -0700

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Recepient Name <hellowmyowndomain.com>

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Full Name <test@gmail.com>

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Contact form

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <@localhost>

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.26 
(https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER:

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME 
format.

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER:

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER:

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the plain text

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER:

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER:

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: <i>You have received a new message!</i>

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER:

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER:

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER:

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER:

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: .

2018-08-09 14:08:16 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Ok: queued as 

2018-08-09 14:08:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

2018-08-09 14:08:16 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 See you later

Message has been sent successfully
```

Comment: Can't you check in Sendgrids interface what happened to the email?

Comment: Why are you disabling certificate verification? That's a really bad idea. Set `SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see what SendGrid says, and then check the status of your submitted messages in their own tools.

Comment: you may also want to read **[this sendgrid documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/Sender_authentication/How_to_set_up_domain_authentication.html)** to setup your domain authentication.

Comment: I edited with debug information.

Comment: On the line `2018-08-09 14:08:16 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Ok: queued as`, you should get that unique string that it provides you, and escalate to [SendGrid Support](https://support.sendgrid.com). They can use that to see what's happening to the message.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly the problem wasn't either in my code or configuration but in the IP my SMTP server is using. My IP is blacklisted and this block my emails. This may happen when you use a Free plan (Shared IP): https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Deliver/Undeliverable_Email/what_do_i_do_if_im_blacklisted.html